# Disable email sending on a legacy Meteor server without redeployment of codes

Tags: meteor

We are facing a strange situation where we have an old legacy Meteor server that we are no longer able to deploy any new codes.

We are moving away from the old server to a new server.

We wanted to keep the old server running as a "reference", but there are cronjobs that still regularly send out emails to clients in the database.

We have to stop these emails from being sent out, without restarting the server or redeploying the codes if possible. Is there any way to do it?

p/s: This is how the server is sending out emails using the Email Meteor package:

```
Meteor.methods({
sendEmail: function(options) {
    // compile the template
    var template = _.template(Assets.getText(options.template));

    if (Meteor.DEBUG) {
        Email.send({
            to: Meteor.EMAIL_ADMIN,
            from: options.from || Meteor.REPLYTO,
            subject: options.subject || '',
            html: template(options.data)
        });
    } else {
        Email.send({
            to: options.to,
            from: options.from || Meteor.REPLYTO,
            subject: options.subject || '',
            html: template(options.data)
        });
    }
},
```

Comment: Why search for a Meteor/code solution? What about a network/server solution where you block the outgoing connection from the server? Or if you're managing the SMTP server, disallow the application from sending emails?

Comment: As Harry Adel pointed out this should be possible but you need at least to restart your Meteor app and remove the `MAIL_URL` in order to prevent errors. Meteor will then silently fail the emails by logging them to the console.

Comment: At the end we changed the password of the email account that is used on the legacy server to send out emails...